# Updating another element on event fire

Tags: javascript, scope

Let's say I have an event attached to one element, but I want to update another element when it fires.

```
var el = document.getElementById("el"),
    el1 = document.getElementById("el1");

el.onmouseover = function() {

    // Here I want to update for example the innerHTML property 
    // of el1 but el1 is undefined in this scope
}
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not so. `el1` is indeed defined in that scope. If it doesn't seem to be, you've probably got an error somewhere. Tested it, even, with this HTML:

```
<p id=el>el
<p id=el1>el1

<script>
var el = document.getElementById("el"),
    el1 = document.getElementById("el1");

el.onmouseover = function() {
  alert(el1);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var el = document.getElementById("el");
el.onmouseover = function () 
{
    var el1 = document.getElementById("el1");
    el1.innerHTML = 'New values';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would it be a pain to get the element inside of the mouseover event?

```
var el = document.getElementById('el');
el.onmouseover = function(evt) {
  var el_inner = evt.target;
  var el2_inner = document.getElementById('el2');
  el2_inner.innerHTML = 'editing the html here.';
};
```